After Shopware update 6.5.5.2 => 6.5.7.0 filter plugin doesn't work
After Shopware update 6.5.5.2 => 6.5.7.0 custom filter plugin doesn't work. It should filter properties depending on another property selected.
Here it is how Subscriber.php class looks:
class Subscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityRepository $optionRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $optionRepository)
    {
        $this->optionRepository = $optionRepository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductListingCriteriaEvent::class => [
                ['onListingCriteria', -200],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function onListingCriteria(ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event): void
    {
        $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('properties');
        $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('properties.group');

        $criteria = $event->getCriteria();
        $filters = $criteria->getExtension('filters');

        if (!$filters instanceof FilterCollection) {
            return;
        }

        $propertyFilter = $filters->get('properties');

        if (!$propertyFilter instanceof Filter || !\is_array($propertyFilter->getValues())) {
            return;
        }

        $currentPropertyOptions = $propertyFilter->getValues();

        $event->getContext()->addExtension('currentPropertyOptionsCriteria', new ArrayEntity($currentPropertyOptions));

        $criteria1 = new Criteria();
        $criteria1->addAssociation('myTags');
        $criteria1->setIds($currentPropertyOptions);

        $tags = new TagCollection();
        $options = $this->optionRepository->search($criteria1, $event->getContext())->getEntities();
        /** @var PropertyGroupOptionEntity $option */
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $extension = $option->getExtension('myTags');
            
            if (!$extension instanceof TagCollection) {
                continue;
            }
            
            $tags->merge($extension);
        }

        $tags = $option->getExtension('myTags');
        $tagnames = $tags->map(fn (TagEntity $tag) => $tag->getName());
        $event->getContext()->addExtension('myTagsNames1', new ArrayEntity($tagnames));

        $prefixes = ['84a5f522d04f463a93a858b3c1bb8f7a','40f24f88c4c34196ad21ec5dcd094e6a', 'e892c99ffc5747848aea3aa5c8126201', '96e839a6e32a4301b238e90088f4a778', 'c5d7bcee60f7493bb6203965e15068e0', '9c493945d37b4ff1b527a874d8315519', 'f032b2d21c484196ad3a98d90379f6c0', 'a07ec367574a4c3d81b7fb6ceae66ffe'];

        if (in_array('3f777000a2734deead391133cee3a6a9', $currentPropertyOptions)) {

            $multiFilter = new MultiFilter(MultiFilter::CONNECTION_OR);

            foreach ($tagnames as $tagname) { $multiFilter->addQuery(new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', $tagname));}

            foreach ($prefixes as $prefix) {
                $multiFilter->addQuery(new EqualsFilter('product.properties.group.id', $prefix));
            }

            $criteria->addFilter($multiFilter);
        }

        ..

        if (in_array('a637fe94fe794a84b0ce7fc2a13e1485', $currentPropertyOptions)) {
            $multiFilter = new MultiFilter(MultiFilter::CONNECTION_OR);

            foreach ($tagnames as $tagname) { $multiFilter->addQuery(new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', $tagname));}

            foreach ($prefixes as $prefix) {
                $multiFilter->addQuery(new EqualsFilter('product.properties.group.id', $prefix));
            }

            $criteria->addFilter($multiFilter);
        }
    }
} 

I try to debug it, but can't find an issue. Associated Properties Tags are in place. But it doesn't filter properties depending on selected one.
Can someone give a tip on debug? Or maybe there is a new way of implementing this kind of custom filtering in Shopware 6.5.7.0 or 6.6 (we are going to update to latest version)?
When we try to reinstall the plugin, we receive this error:
Internal Server Error: Table "myfilter_property_group_option_tag" has to be prefixed with "custom_entity_ or ce_"

UPDATE:
I think we can skip updating database fields names for now.
What I have found is filter stop filtering out properties starting from Showpare 6.5.7.0 version.
The only filter related update issue I found is this, but can't make it useful for now: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/v6.5.7.0/changelog/release-6-5-7-0/2023-11-03-fix-dynamic-product-listing-filter.md
Also I found, that cache could cause the issue and this version has an update enabling this cache: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/v6.5.7.0/changelog/release-6-5-7-0/2022-09-29-cms-navigation-http-cache.md
But disabling it via .env here doesn't help: SHOPWARE_HTTP_CACHE_ENABLED="0"

You debugged it and you cannot reproduce your issue during debugging -or- you could not summon any diagnostics that would have lead you to a potential cause? Just asking, because in the first case, it is much more hard to tackle with ("Heisenbug") but in the later, you should edit your question and share in your own words and understanding what you have already checked during debugging. There is also a third option with software from a vendor, like Shopware, and that is if you assume a defect you report it to support. Please clarify.

I check the code for errors and tried to figure out updates using search and AI. I can not apply any other diagnostics that would lead me to fix this. If you can advice, it could be helpful.

My advice would be make use of a binary search to find out which version exactly introduces the observed defect and the latest known good version. Then to review the changes between those two versions.

After update to Shopware 6.5.7.0 our filter plugin stopped working.
